# How to Backup a webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

The problem is I reinstalled my computer and the backup didn't work so now all my sourcecode is gone... But my webservice is still running on a webserver.

When I upload the new website the old site will be deleted, so how can i backup the webservice and make it a part of my new website?

In the bin folder of the webserver there is some strange name files like App_web_cjcpmkr8.dll,
can I just download these files and .asmx files? Isnt there then missing a link between the files? How can I see which .asmx files uses which .dll files?

Comment: I createt the webservices again from the begining however I used reflector to get the header of the webmethods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately they're all compiled- depending on your site's config, there will be either one assembly per page or per directory. You can download all the DLLs and decompile them through [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)- the decompiled class names should help you match them up with the corresponding markup, but you'll still have some reconstructive surgery to do.

Comment: The FileDisassembler will help if you're using Reflector as it can dump all the files out to the file system:  http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The magic link between the asmx and the dlls lies in the name of the bin folder. IIS will automatically look for dlls in this folder. You should be able to deploy your web service on a new web server by just copying the files. I recommend that you try to set up a copy of the service on a new web server, before you delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

If this is critical data get a service to try and get your files back. If not then moving forward invest in an online backup solution / source control utility.

This will save you tons of time when this happens again.  I use source control on a remote server combined with a subscription to Carbonite locally to ensure that I don't lose that precious data; both the data checked in and the data that I'm currently working on.  It's Iike $45 a year and well worth it.

As for your data I'm sorry that you've lost it.  I'm sure you’re not the first to have this happen.